# What is the best practice for retrieving and downloading mass data from SQL Server using Flex/Actionscript

Tags: sql-server-2008, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, windows-server-2008

I have a Flex web-based application that retrieves data from SQL Server and displays it in a data grid. I'm using FileReference to export the data from data grid into a CSV file, which is fine for small amount of data. I need another method for retrieving and downloading massive data directly without  displaying it in the data grid. I was thinking it must be a way to export data on the server using SQL server (like using OPENROWSET method) and then download the exported file. But I couldn't implement it so far. Also I'm not sure if it is the best  approach to do such task. I was wondering if anybody could help me out to find a solution for it. I really appreciate it.

I'm using IIS 7 as web server and [Adobe Flex Connector for MS SQL Server](http://www.flexappsstore.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=65) as web service to connect to SQL Server

Comment: Since this is all going to happen on the server side (you'll generate a big csv file and download that), there's no Flex involved (aside from `navigateUrl()`-ing to the download page). You'd better provide us with some information on the server-side technology you're using and tag your question accordingly, so the right people can come in and help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've updated my tag to show that I'm using Windows Server 2008. However I may not sure if I get your point correctly. I still think my question is about Flex as I need to develop the code in Flex Dev. Environment. Is that right?

Comment: Do you mean you have no web server between your flex front-end and your database?

Comment: Oh Yes. I use IIS 7 as web server and Flex connector to connect to SQL Server. I've updated the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FileReference.download(URLRequest) to download the file directly from the remote server. The file itself should be created on the server side. For example, if you use ASP.NET, you can create a service (WCF, Fluorine etc) that fetches data from the DB, puts it into generated file and returns the url of the file to Flex client which can then use FileReference.download.

Comment: Does FileReference.download load the file in memory? Or does it stream it directly to the disk? In the former case it wouldn't be a good solution for large files.

Comment: Dunno. There is nothing about it in the documentation. But I can guess that it streams data directly into the disk, otherwise it would be quite illogical.

Comment: I used FileReference.save method to export data from the Data Grid in my first solution. But I've never used the  FileReference.download method. I'm going to test it. But first, I need to create the web-service for generating the Excel file. Do you have any sample for such services in ASP.NET? I was thinking that I can create a Stored procedure in SQL Server for it, but if I can create a web service that would be much better. thank you.

Comment: You can write your web services either using AMF based solution, such as FluorineFx (free) or WebOrb (paid) if you want fast data transfer or you can use WCF to write SOAP based web services (those can be quite slow if you transfer a lot of data). AMF based web services can be reached via RemoteObject while WCF ones can be easily imported via service wizard (in Flash Builder).

Comment: Here is what I've done: instead of web-service, I developed a Stored Prc. in SQL server using OPENROWSET function to export data. I developed 3 functions in flex to export and download data: The first function copies an excel template into a folder for exporting data. this file is required by OPENROWSET. the second function runs after the first one. It sends a request to SQL Server to export data using OPENROWSET. Finally the third function downloads the file using navigateToURL function. Thank you both .